# Two bunnies meeting

Tags: python

This is the problem I'm trying to solve:

> Given a straight line with the starting point "O". Two hares begin simultaneously moving along this straight line away from this point. They started at different distances from point O.

I need to create a function in the programming language Python, which will show at what distance from the point O the hares will meet.

There are values:

- starting position (several units) from point O
- jump length (several units) overcome in one jump
- the duration of the rest (sleep)
- after each jump the hares must rest(sleep).

It shows how long (how many time units) the hare will rest between two jumps. The jump itself lasts 0 units. 
It is known that all values ​​are integers:

- position> = 0
- jump length> = 0
- duration of rest (sleep)> = 1

I need to write a function that uses all of the named values ​​for both of the hares and can show

- -1 if the hares will never meet
- the position where they will meet for the first time. The meeting takes place on the ground, but not at the last second of rest.

Here is my code:

```
from fractions import Fraction

def meet_me(pos1, jump_distance1, sleep1, pos2, jump_distance2, sleep2):
        if pos1 == pos2:
            pos1 = pos2
        elif (jump_distance1 / sleep1 > jump_distance2 / sleep2 and pos1 > pos2) or (jump_distance2 / sleep2 > jump_distance1 / sleep1 and pos2 > pos1):
            pos1 = -1
        elif jump_distance1 / sleep1 == jump_distance2 / sleep2:
            pos1 = -1
        else:
            if pos1 > pos2:
                while pos1 != pos2:
                    pos1 += Fraction(jump_distance1, sleep1)
                    pos2 += Fraction(jump_distance2, sleep2)
                    if pos2 > pos1:
                        pos1 = -1
                        break
            elif pos2 > pos1:
                while pos1 != pos2:
                    pos1 += Fraction(jump_distance1, sleep1)
                    pos2 += Fraction(jump_distance2, sleep2)
                    if pos1 > pos2:
                        pos1 = -1
                        break
        return pos1

print(meet_me(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1))   # = > 3
print(meet_me(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1))  # => 3
print(meet_me(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5))  # => -1
print(meet_me(3, 5, 10, 4, 1, 2))  # => 8
print(meet_me(100, 7, 4, 300, 8, 6))  # => 940
print(meet_me(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))  # => -1
print(meet_me(10, 7, 7, 5, 8, 6))   # => 45
print(meet_me(1, 7, 1, 15, 5, 1))   # => 50
```

This is my expected output:

```
3
3
-1
8
940
-1
45
50
```

I can not understand what I'm doing wrong. This is the output I'm getting:

```
1
-1
-1
940
-1
25
50
```

Comment: I think you need to give a bit more explanation of the problem. From your code it looks like the Hares are each moving every second a distance of jump_distance/sleep. Possibly they're supposed to move and then sleep. You've only given us 7 of the 8 outputs so hard to tell which is which, but for the second one ((1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1)) they start at the same position, so it seems like the right answer should be 1, not 3.

Comment: Is your indentation right? I see your `elif` indented inside your first `if`, they should be at the same level.

Comment: There's lots of information missing from the original problem statement. What are `jump_distanceN` and `sleepN`, how do they relate to the problem?

Comment: It seems to me like this should be a simple high school algebra problem, and not require a computer program to solve it.

Comment: Regardless, the question is too wide in scope -- it's not asking about a programming problem other developers may encounter (or presenting a problem where you already isolated a specific language construct or library call behaving contrary to expectations with a [mcve] for that specific failure), but asking for someone to debug your program logic for you. The former is what this site is here for; the latter is not.

Comment: The 4th case doesn't meet at 8 because this is simulation (time passed, pos1, pos2): (0, 3, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (3, 3, 5), (4, 3, 6), ..., (9, 3, 8), (10, 8, 9). That was 2nd's last second on 8 so they never met. What I want to say is I think there is something wrong with this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me longer than I expected but here's my solution which gives the answers you were looking for.

You have two problems I can see. The first is that you are checking whether they are equal before they move, which the problem seems to suggest shouldn't happen;

see example 2 : print(meet_me(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1))  # => 3 rather than 1

and the second is that you are treating the hares as continuously moving, rather than moving and then resting as the problem asks. A slower hare can be behind the faster one and overtake it a few times before being left behind, so you have to do a more complex check to see if they'll never meet.

```
from fractions import Fraction

def meet_me(pos1, jump_distance1, sleep1, pos2, jump_distance2, sleep2):

        speed_1 = Fraction(jump_distance1, sleep1)
        speed_2 = Fraction(jump_distance2, sleep2)

        # Check which hare is slower. If equal speed, set slower_hare to 1.
        if speed_2 >= speed_1:
            slower_hare = 1
        else:
            slower_hare = 2

        distance_between_hares = None

        slower_just_moved = False

        current_position_1 = pos1
        current_position_2 = pos2

        # How long do they have left to sleep?
        current_sleep_remaining_1 = 0
        current_sleep_remaining_2 = 0


        # Do the loop.
        while True:
            # Check if the hares are still sleeping, and if not, jump and reset the sleep timer.
            if current_sleep_remaining_1 == 0:
                current_position_1 += jump_distance1
                current_sleep_remaining_1 = sleep1
                if slower_hare == 1:
                    slower_just_moved = True


            if current_sleep_remaining_2 == 0:
                current_position_2 += jump_distance2
                current_sleep_remaining_2 = sleep2
                if slower_hare == 2:
                    slower_just_moved = True


            current_sleep_remaining_1 -= 1
            current_sleep_remaining_2 -= 1


            # Check to see if they're at the same position.
            if current_position_1 == current_position_2:
                return current_position_1

            # Check if they will never meet. If the slower hare is behind the faster one, and after moving gets further behind,
            # or stays same distance as it was the previous time it jumped, then it will never catch up.
            if slower_just_moved:
                if slower_hare == 1:
                    if current_position_1 < current_position_2:
                        previous_distance_between_hares = distance_between_hares
                        distance_between_hares = current_position_2 - current_position_1
                        if previous_distance_between_hares != None and distance_between_hares >= previous_distance_between_hares:
                            return -1
                if slower_hare == 2:
                    if current_position_2 < current_position_1:
                        previous_distance_between_hares = distance_between_hares
                        distance_between_hares = current_position_1 - current_position_2
                        if previous_distance_between_hares != None and distance_between_hares >= previous_distance_between_hares:
                            return -1

            slower_just_moved = False
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my proposal
it does not, however, return expected values, but read my comment on that topic (i think solutions are wrong)

anyway,
if nothing, you can adapt my code (something like that should work as expected)

```
from fractions import Fraction

def meet_me(p1, x1, t1, p2, x2, t2):
    if p1 == p2:
        # if they are already on the same place, they met at that position
        return p1
    elif Fraction(x1, t1) == Fraction(x2, t2):
        # same speed but different positions like in 4th case (reed my comment about that)
        return -1

    if p2 < p1:
        # to ensure that 1st is lesser
        p2, p1 = p1, p2
        x2, x1 = x1, x2
        t2, t1 = t1, t2

    # simulation by seconds (it can also be by gcd(t1, t2))
    time = 1    # 1 or gcd assuming they do not jump instantly
    while p1 != p2:
        if not time % t2:
            if p2 < p1:
                #p2 < p1 which means speed1 > speed2 since at begining p1 < p2
                # 2nd will make even greater distance between that 1st won't catch up with
                return -1
            p2 += x2
        if not time % t1:
            p1 += x1
        time += 1 # or gcd
    return p1
```